# Most Efficient Method to Convert Set Type?

Tags: apex, performance, set, serialization, typecast

I have a twist on [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42255/convert-a-setid-to-setstring-in-apex-salesforce). What is the relative performance of each of the following methods?

**Via [Peter Knolle](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/154/peter-knolle)**:

```
public static Set<String> deserializeToStrings(Set<Id> input)
{
    return (Set<String>)JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(input), Set<String>.class);
}
```

**Via [Jenny B](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/10038/jenny-b) (and [sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2984/sfdcfox))**:

```
public static Set<String> stringify(Set<Id> input)
{
    return new Set<String>(String.join(new List<id>(input), ',').split(','));
}
```

**Via [E.J. Wilburn](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/7/e-j-wilburn)**:

```
public static Set<String> castToStrings(Set<Id> input)
{
    return new Set<String>((List<String>)new List<Id>(input));
}
```

I have been using the third methodology and I am curious if it is more or less efficient than the others.

Comment: Adrian -- option 2 fails when the `input` is an empty list; the resulting set<String> has one element with value equal to empty string because `split()` on an empty list results in a list of size 1 with member[0] value = empty string. Option 2 has to be written more 'cleverly'

Comment: @crop1645 I think they're all missing null checks too. I just wanted to analyze what was out there from a performance perspective. Good point though, it can certainly be improved (which would probably slow it down a tad bit more).

Comment: options 1 and 3 are fine as is on empty `set<id> input`; only option 2 has the issue

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Approach**

This should be my final update. I reran my tests, setting all `Debug Levels` to `NONE` except `Apex`, which I set to `ERROR`. The findings are more or less unchanged: **casting beats all other approaches**. I added more data, however, to demonstrate the level of difference more rigorously.

I used the following strategy to profile the above in `Execute Anonymous`:

```
static Set<Id> generateDummyIds(Integer size)
{
    Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();
    for (Integer i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        String suffix = String.valueOf(i).leftPad(15).replace(' ', '0');
        ids.add(Id.valueOf('001' + suffix));
    }
    return ids;
}
final Integer SET_ELEMENTS = 0;
final Integer ITERATIONS = 1000;

Set<Id> input = generateDummyIds(SET_ELEMENTS);
Long start = Datetime.now().getTime();
for (Integer i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) PerformanceTesting.deserializeToStrings(input);
system.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, Datetime.now().getTime() - start);
```

I used the following value combinations ten times each:

- `SET_ELEMENTS = 0` with `ITERATIONS = 1000` for 10k sample size
- `SET_ELEMENTS = 1` with `ITERATIONS = 1000` for 10k sample size
- `SET_ELEMENTS = 1000` with `ITERATIONS = 50` for 500 sample size
- `SET_ELEMENTS = 100000` with `ITERATIONS = 1` for 10 sample size

---

**Modifications**

I added a fourth method out of curiosity, even though OP of that question requested to avoid it. This method provides a baseline against which to measure alternatives.

```
public static Set<String> loopToStrings(Set<Id> input)
{
    Set<String> output = new Set<String>();
    for (Id id : input) output.add(id);
    return output;
}
```

I also modified the `stringify` method to produce the correct results as noted by @crop1645:

```
public static Set<String> stringify(Set<Id> input)
{
    return (input == null || input.isEmpty()) ? new Set<String>() :
        new Set<String>(String.join(new List<id>(input), ',').split(','));
}
```

---

**Data**

Of note is that the `deserializeToStrings` and `stringify` methods both failed with 100k elements in the set. The former failed due to heap size exceeded, the latter got a `REGEX_TOO_COMPLICATED` error.

First let's take a look at **milliseconds per call**:

```
                  0       1      1k         100k
deserialize  0.2498  0.2118  14.290   HEAP ERROR
stringify    0.0657  0.1023   2.276  REGEX ERROR
loop         0.0465  0.0914  17.164       1705.4
cast         0.0385  0.0594   2.000        210.0
```

[image: Chart - Milliseconds Per Call]

Next let's examine **calls per second**:

```
                 0        1     1k           100k
deserialize   4003     4272     70     HEAP ERROR
stringify    15221     9775    439    REGEX ERROR
loop         21505    10941     58           0.59
cast         25974    16835    500           4.76
```

[image: Chart - Calls Per Second]

Comment: So, I'd go with the direct cast-to-strings, then. I learned something new today.

Comment: In fact, it is the only approach that significantly beats out looping.

Comment: there have been a rash of these 'which is better' posts recently - perhaps you could collect them all into a consolidated blog post that is SEO; as noted in my comment to the OP, option 2 needs enhancement